# PHP Serialization of Class that references itself

Tags: php, serialization

To give some context; this process was working prior to adding in the Serializable interface. The `TestAction2` is not keeping a reference to itself after unserializing; and I have tried adding the `Serializable` to the `Action` class and telling it to serialize the `$parent` but still no difference. It is correctly unserializing the `$method` field though.

Class `Action` serializes the reference in `$parent` field when the serialization is being done on the class that is referencing it (`class B`), but not when it references itself. Something with serializing happening on Class `A` or `B` but not the `Action` class itself.

```
class A implements Serializable {
    private static $label;

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(self::$label);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        self::$label = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private $actions;

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize([
                'actions' => $this->actions,
                'parent' => parent::serialize()]);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        $data = unserialize($serialized);
        $this->actions = $data['actions'];
        parent::unserialize($data['parent']);
    }

    public function addAction($anAction) {
        $this->actions[] = $anAction;
    }

    public function process() {
        $this->addAction(new TestAction1($this, 'test1')); // WORKS FINE
        $this->addAction(new TestAction2($this, 'test2')); // WORKS NOT!
    }
}

class Action {
    private $parent;
    private $method;

    public function __construct($cParent, $sMethod) {
        $this->parent = $cParent;
    }
}

class TestAction1 extends Action {
    public function __construct($cParent, $sMethod) {
        parent::__construct($cParent, $sMethod);
    }
}
class TestAction2 extends Action {
    private $maybeNeedLater;
    public function __construct($cParent, $sMethod) {
        $this->maybeNeedLater = $cParent;
        parent::__construct($this, $sMethod); // pass $this instead
    }
}


$testThis = new B();
$testThis->process();
$serialized = serialize($testThis);
$testThis = unserialize($serialized);
```

The `Action` class `TestAction2` will have a null `$parent` field in the `$actions` field of `$testThis`

Comment: Typo in parent::__constsruct?

Comment: excuse the typo; this code was not copy/paste. Just trying to get input on what may be causing the Action class to not serialize itself; why is it null?

Comment: You need to implement the `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` magic methods to save and recreate the links between objects.

Comment: @Barmar PHP documentation specifies I can use the `Serializable` interface in place of the magic methods; and this was all working before I had implemented the `Serializable` interface on the class A that is holding reference to the `Action` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two different Action classes a bit of a red herring, because they are not the problem. Test2 just happens to use a reference other than $testThis; and many other reference would be wrong as well.

The real problem is that the order of serialization in your A/B classes is different from the order of unserialization. During serialization PHP encodes references with r (or R) and a number (r and R are different in many ways but the difference would just distract from the counting issue). In your example $needThis can be referenced with r:1;, A::label with r:2;, the actions array with r:3;, and so on. The $this reference to the TestAction2 object is r:8; (you can see this when you echo $serialized.)

When you call unserialize inside your unserialize function, there is no A::label (yet). Because of that all numbers greater than 1 will be off by one. r:8; now points to whatever is in maybeNeedLater.

Now things get a little complicated, because PHP normally does not create such strings. In PHP5 it seems to create some kind of error that is printed as NULL. In PHP7 parent will actually be a reference to $needThis.

Luckily there are a few easy ways to solve this:

**Option 1:**

Use a different format to encode your parent class:

```
class A implements Serializable {
  private static $label;

  public function serialize() {
    return json_encode(self::$label);
  }
  public function unserialize($serialized) {
    self::$label = json_decode($serialized);
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use double serialization in your child class and make sure the order fits:

```
class B extends A {
private $actions;

public function serialize() {
    return json_encode([
            'actions' => serialize($this->actions),
            'parent' => parent::serialize()]);
}
public function unserialize($serialized) {
    $data = json_decode($serialized, true);
    $this->actions = unserialize($data['actions']);
    parent::unserialize($data['parent']);
}
...
```